# Google url shortener: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-url-shortener

My Wordpress theme uses [this](https://github.com/tolgaergin/social/blob/master/assets/javascripts/socialShare.js) jQuery plugin for social sharing. I want to shorten the sharing Url with Google Url shortening api.

I used [this](http://hayageek.com/google-url-shortener-api/) tutorial:
I added `makeShort()` function to social share section in `wp-content/themes/woodstock/js/wstock-plugins.js` file like this:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.extend({

    socialShare: function(options) {

    var defaults = {
      social: '',
      title: document.title,
      shareUrl: makeShort(),
      description: $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content'),
      /*Other defaults ... */
     };

    function makeShort(){
      var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
        'resource': {
        'longUrl': window.location.href
        }
      });
      request.execute(function(response){
        shortUrl = response.id;
      });
      return shortUrl;
    }
  });
});
```

And changed a script in my index page to:

```
function googleLoad(){
  gapi.client.setApiKey('API_CODE');
  gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1',function(){});
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  googleLoad();       
    jQuery('.social-sharing').socialShare({
        social: 'twitter,facebook,google,pinterest',
        animation:'launchpadReverse',
        blur:true
    }); 
});
```

But I'm getting this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined` on this line:

```
gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert
```

[This](https://vrbazaar.ir/product/%D9%87%D8%AF%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%B9%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D9%85%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B2%DB%8C-oculus-rift-dk2/) is a link with this issue on my website.

I don't know what is wrong...

Comment: `makeShort()` is executed before `gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1',function(){});` has finished its work -> [`gapi.client.load(name, version, callback)`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientloadname--------version--------callback)

Comment: I suspected that, But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: When `urlshortener` is available `callback` is executed. Hence the earliest possible moment `makeShort()` should be called is in the `callback` of `gapi.client.load()` + [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)